# Android initialize toggle buttons with tags

Tags: android, togglebutton

In my program I have multiple togglebuttons and I need to initialize them with tags instead of id's in the for loop like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< Grid.GRID_SIZE*Grid.GRID_SIZE ; i++){
        toggleButtons[i] = (ToggleButton)table.findViewWithTag(i);
}
```

And I want to paint them black like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< Grid.GRID_SIZE*Grid.GRID_SIZE ; i++){
        toggleButtons[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

}

But it gives nullpointer exception becasue of I initialized them with tags, any suggestions?